# JDBC module on JBoss EAP 6.1+

Tags: java, mysql, jboss

I'm trying to connecto to an mysql database in my JSF aplication, but when i run ti on my server (I'm using JBoss EAP 6.1+) i get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from [Module "deployment.e-r.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

I know that i have to add mysql connector to the server (I have downloaded mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin) an added it as an external JAR to my project, only to find out I must add it to the JBoss server. All the tutorials i have found are for an AS 7 server and don't seem to work for me. Could I please get step by step instructions on how to add mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin to JBoss 6.1+

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

(A) Deploy the mysql driver jar from your JBoss console:
 1) Browse the console page localhost:9990/console.
  *[your port can be different based on your configuration]*
 2) Deploy the driver jar, and enable deployment.

(B) If this doesn't work for you, then alternately you have to manually add the jar to your `JBOSS_HOME/modules/` directory. It will be:

1) create directory under the modules directory as `com/mysql/jdbc/main`.
 2) place the driver jar inside the newly created directory.
 3) also, create a file module.xml that will contains things like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql.jdbc">
  <resources>
     <resource-root path="YOUR_mysql-connector-xxx_NAME.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
     <module name="javax.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```